# Как правильно поставить ударение в кратком прилагательном?

Tags: орфоэпия

Утверждение вЕрно или утверждение вернО? Как правильно?

Answer (score 2):

Прилагательное *верный* имеет следующие краткие формы:

**ве́рен, верна́, ве́рно, ве́рны, верны́.**

Правильно будет сказать так: *утверждение ве́рно* ( ср.р. ).

Answer (score 1):

Верно "в**Е**рно", а "верн**о**" неверно.

Ударение на последний слог падает в женском роде ("Но я другому отдана; я буду век ему верна") и оба ударения допустимы в слове "верны".

> Ве́рны сладостной приманке,
>   Они едут на закат,
>   И смущаясь
>   поселянки
>   Долго им вослед глядят.

Н. С. Гумилев, «По дороге их владений…»

> Но когда ее муж-проходимец, пиратствуя,
>   Срубил двухсотлетние три
>   сосны
>   В саду ее детства и она не препятствовала,
>   Я понял, что
>   слухи про нее верны́.

Игорь Северянин, Сосны ее детства